# Spacing on mobile version bootstrap 4.2.1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, spacing

I've got some weird spaces in the mobile version, here some images:

Here's how does it look on desktop:

[Desktop #01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLsEC.png)

[Desktop #02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6nIX.png)

And a mobile:

[Mobile #01 - with spacing on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByNVq.jpg)

[Mobile #02 - with a "h3 class="display-4" maybe calling that spacing?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7j5F.jpg)

HTML:

```
<!-- The beginning of html -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="PL-pl">
<head>
  <title>The page is being rebuilt...</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- versioning can often help (href="css/style.css?ver=2.0") -->
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP 4 -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://reportsquestionsznaczki65.000webhostapp.com/css/restyled.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-white text-center bg-info nomarginbottom">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="display-2">This site is being finally rebuilt!</h3>
            <p class="lead">Hence it will have more features soon.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mt-3 text-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h3 class="display-4">Sites done:</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-2 text-white text-center mb-4">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                <a class="websitelink" href="https://reportsquestionsznaczki65.000webhostapp.com/wszyscy.html">    
                    <div class="box lead p-4">Go to: "WSZYSCY"</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-12 change"><h4 class="display-4">What will be changed?</h4></div>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="row change2">
                <p class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead">The structure of the page.</p> <!-- class feature not used -->
                <p class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead">The site will be now responsive.</p>
                <p class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead">Lessons will be adding automatically via JS.</p>
                <p class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead">More code, more readable..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="row change2">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead"><p>Sleek look.</p></div> 
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead"><p>Fast and comprehensive.</p></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead"><p>Inspiring quotes.</p></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 feature lead"><p>And much more...</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row change2">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h5 class="text-center border border-3 border-dashed border-info change3 nomarginbottom">
                    <q>You can do everything, unless your imagination has stopped you.</q>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row change2">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h3 class="display-4 text-center nomarginbottom">Current status: Learning Bootstrap 4.2 (80%) + Added "wszyscy.html".</h3>
                <p class="lead text-center nomarginbottom">Overall status: 5% done on the page.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h5 class="text-center  border border-3 border-dashed border-info change3 nomarginbottom">
                    <q>Change is best, when it's changing with you, not without.</q>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
 </main>       





<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://reportsquestionsznaczki65.000webhostapp.com/noscript.html"/>
</noscript>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS (restyled.css):

```
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* Rebuilding the page */
.change {
    padding: 30px 10px;
    background-color: #dedede;
}
.change2 {
    padding: 15px 5px;
}
.change3 {
    padding: 20px 5px;
}
.nomargin {
    margin: 0;
}
.nomarginbottom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
img[alt="www.000webhost.com"] {
    display: none;
}
.border-3 {
    border-width: 3px !important;
}
.border-dashed {
    border-style: dashed !important;
}
.websitelink, .websitelink:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
.box {
    background-color: #343a40;
    font-size: 170%;
}
.box:hover {
    background-color: darkslategray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's the website :

https://reportsquestionsznaczki65.000webhostapp.com

Due to it's online you can use:

view-source:https://reportsquestionsznaczki65.000webhostapp.com/index.html
https://reportsquestionsznaczki65.000webhostapp.com/css/restyled.css

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What mobile browser are you seeing the extra spacing in? I tested in Chrome and everything looks fine.

Comment: your `nomarginbottom` class create problems in less than 350 resolution so remove `display-4` and give perfect font-size to it

Comment: Mobile version on Chrome and Firefox I've tested, both has the same thing, deleting the class "nomarginbottom" or deleting font-size attribute in CSS haven't changed anything. My phone width is 360px

Comment: Adding a new class "display-5" with lower font-size has helped

Comment: I've added a new class "display-5" in which I've written different font size to 2
5 rem and set it to the heading that actually was out of the page.

Thanks for your conclusions!

Answer (score 0):

The text "wszyscy.html" in the mobile version is bigger than the screen due to its font-size . Make that smaller and you will no longer see that space

Comment: That didn't change anything

Comment: If you see these two images attached , the spacing has disappeared when i changed the font size of .display-4 from 3.5rem to 2.5 rem . Have you done exaclty that ?
(1) https://ibb.co/WfMWGsz
(2) https://ibb.co/4gQHd7N

Comment: Yes I've done the same and it disappeared, now I have a fully responsive website. I've managed to see that I'm lacking of a meta tag for a viewport as well, dum dum ..